# Changing span of several checkboxes with single javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am stuck on this, I am new in HTML/JavaScript code. I am trying to create an HTML code where checkboxes must change an image span (or caption) to "CORREGIDO". So, many images have a reference number on their caption but when the checkbox of that image is clicked, must change the string into "CORREGIDO". My HTML code so far is the following:

```
<ul class="galeria">
    <li><a href="#img1"><img src="Foto1.jpg"   onerror="this.style.display='none'"/> <input class="confirmation" type="checkbox"  id="exp1">  </a>
        <h2><span class="spanTxt []">OT:   4251678</span> <span class="spanTxt [] hidden"> CORREGIDO </span></h2></li> 
    <li><a href="#img2"><img src="Foto2.jpg"   onerror="this.style.display='none'"/> <input class="confirmation" type="checkbox"  id="exp2"> </a>
        <h2><span class="spanTxt []">OT:   4876852</span> <span class="spanTxt [] hidden"> CORREGIDO </span></h2></li>
 </ul>
```

So far it works for a single picture. But the JavaScript is made for a single checkbox "id". This JavaScript code I took it from this webpage. The script I am using is:

```
document.getElementById('exp1').addEventListener('change', function(e) {changeDisplay()})

function changeDisplay() 
    {document.querySelectorAll('.spanTxt').forEach(function(elem) {elem.classList.toggle('hidden')})}
```

Maybe is not he best approach for this...

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript code that you're using,

```
document.getElementById('exp1').addEventListener('change', function(e) {changeDisplay()})

function changeDisplay() 
    {document.querySelectorAll('.spanTxt').forEach(function(elem) {elem.classList.toggle('hidden')})}
```

only has one `document.getElementById('exp1').addEventListener('change', function(e) {changeDisplay()})`
when there should be two.

Here is a fix that includes both of them,

```
document.getElementById('exp1').addEventListener('change', function(e) {changeDisplay(e)})
document.getElementById('exp2').addEventListener('change', function(e) {changeDisplay(e)})

function changeDisplay(e) 
    {e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.children[1].classList.toggle('hidden')}
```

I changed the function changeDisplay(e) because the `forEach()` function was getting in the way when manipulating both of the elements. The code correctly hides the 'CORREGIDO' when the checkbox is unchecked and shows it when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to change my code for multiple checkboxes. Ill doing a personal webpage so maybe I use 30 pics with a checkbox each. Instead of adding another line on the script, is there any option?

Comment: Yes there is, sorry for not thinking of that. `document.querySelectorAll('.confirmation').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('change', e => {
    changeDisplay(e);
  })
})`

should fix that.

Comment: My god... I spent days thinking about this... haha really thank you!!